# ionic Object(...) is not a function at DocumentViewer.viewDocument :

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to load a pdf from the assets folder in ionic or to download one. I've watched some tutorials but all of them are giving me the same error.

Ionic:

- ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (C:\Users\hanna\node_modules\ionic)
- Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
- @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

- cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
- Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0, browser 5.0.4
- Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 7 other plugins)

System:

- NodeJS : v9.4.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
- npm    : 5.6.0
- OS     : Windows 10

The code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DocumentViewer, DocumentViewerOptions } from '@ionic- 
native/document-viewer/ngx';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/File/ngx';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
 constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
private file: File,
private ft: FileTransfer,
private document: DocumentViewer,
public platform: Platform
) {}
openLocalPdf() {
// let filePath = this.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/assets';

    // if (this.platform.is('android') || this.platform.is('browser')) {
//   let fakeName = Date.now();
//   this.file.copyFile(filePath, 'Typescript_Jumpstart_Book_Udemy.pdf', this.file.dataDirectory, `${fakeName}.pdf`).then(result => {
//     this.fileOpener.open(result.nativeURL, 'application/pdf')
//       .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
//       .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
//   })
// } else {
//   // Use Document viewer for iOS for a better UI
//   const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
//     title: 'My PDF'
//   }
//   this.document.viewDocument(`${filePath}/5-tools.pdf`, 'application/pdf', options);
// }
console.log('Documents Pressed.....');

    const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
  title: "My PDF"
}
this.document.viewDocument('assets/Typescript_Jumpstart_Book_Udemy.pdf', 'application/pdf', options)
console.log('Documents Pressed..... afterrr');

  }
  downloadAndOpenPdf() {
let path = null;
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
  path = this.file.documentsDirectory;
} else {
  path = this.file.dataDirectory;
}

    const transfer = this.ft.create();
transfer.download('https://devdactic.com/html/5-simple-hacks-LBT.pdf', path + 'MyFile.pdf').then(entry => {
  let url = entry.toURL();

      this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
  // this.fileOpener.open(url, 'application/pdf')
  // .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
  // .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
 });
  }
}
```

the Error is :

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at DocumentViewer.viewDocument (index.js:29)
at HomePage.webpackJsonp.193.HomePage.openLocalPdf (home.ts:43)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (HomePage.html:10)
at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
at core.js:10629
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2628)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on Ionic 3, and you are using plugin version supported for Ionic 4. Use the plugins supported for Ionic 3 by going through Ionic v3 document.

**Reference**: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/

**Step 1**

Un-install all your native plugins.

**Step 2**

Install version 4. Example below

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-document-viewer
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/document-viewer@4
```

**Step 3**

Don't append **ngx** at the end of the import, it's only for Angular 6.

```
import { DocumentViewer } from '@ionic-native/document-viewer';
```

**Step 4:**

Repeat Step 2 and 3 for your other native plugins.

Comment: Yes, Right answer

Comment: i am facing same problem do i need to downgrade the ionic cli version also?